# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.my_app/com.example.my_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to display the data on mysql on and android app

this is my code
package com.example.my_app;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    /* Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 {
@SuppressWarnings(“deprecation”)
public void onClick(View view)
{*/
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.43.70/my_app/demo.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        Log.e("log_tag", "connection success");
        //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), “pass”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        //convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso - 8859 - 1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), “Input Reading pass”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            is.close();

            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        //parse json data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            TableLayout tv = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
            tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            int flag = 1;
            for (int i = -1; i < jArray.length() - 1; i++) {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                if (flag == 1) {
                    TextView b6 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    b6.setText("Id");
                    b6.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    b6.setTextSize(15);
                    tr.addView(b6);
                    TextView b19 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    b19.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                    b19.setTextSize(15);
                    b19.setText("name");
                    b19.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    tr.addView(b19);
                    TextView b29 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    b29.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                    b29.setText("age");
                    b29.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    b29.setTextSize(15);
                    tr.addView(b29);
                    tv.addView(tr);
                    final View vline = new View(MainActivity.this);
                    vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2));
                    vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    tv.addView(vline);
                    flag = 0;
                } else {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag”, ”id: " + json_data.getInt("Id") + ", Username: " + json_data.getString("username") + ", No: " + json_data.getString("comment"), null);
                    TextView b = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    String stime = String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("Id"));
                    b.setText(stime);
                    b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    b.setTextSize(15);
                    tr.addView(b);
                    TextView b1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                    b1.setTextSize(15);
                    String stime1 = json_data.getString("username");
                    b1.setText(stime1);
                    b1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tr.addView(b1);
                    TextView b2 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                    String stime2 = json_data.getString("comment");
                    b2.setText(stime2);
                    b2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    b2.setTextSize(15);
                    tr.addView(b2);
                    tv.addView(tr);
                    final View vline1 = new View(MainActivity.this);
                    vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
                    vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tv.addView(vline1);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

> my errors are
>
> ```
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
> Unable to start activity 
> ComponentInfo{com.example.my_app/com.example.my_app.MainActivity}: 
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at 
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at 
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at 
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at  
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at 
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at 
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at 
>
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.example.my_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:107)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at 
>
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
> 07-21 03:33:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     ... 11 more
> ```

my android manifest is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.my_app" 
     android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application android:allowBackup="true" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name="com.example.my_app.MainActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

my activity main is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
      android:focusable="true">

    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/table"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
          android:focusable="true"></TableLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

my php file is

```
<?php
$username ='root';
$password ='';
$hostname ='localhost';
$database ='my_app';

$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db($database,localhost);
$i=mysql_query(“select * from smart healthcare”);

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($i);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($i))
{

$r[]=$row;
$check=$row['Id'];
}

if($check==NULL)
{
$r[$num_rows]=”Record is not available”;
print(json_encode($r));
}
else
{
$r[$num_rows]=”success”;
print(json_encode($r));
}

mysql_close($localhost);
?>
```

Comment: The error message indicates a problem with JsonArray and the line 107 in MainActivity, reviewing the code you posted appears that the line numbers are not the same that when you created the error message, review the server response to see if the json object contains all intended objects, if you can indicate us the exact line with the crash we could provide more detail.

Comment: yes i cahnged those and now my app is opening but the table is not being displayed on the app. the error i am getting now is  08-11 18:23:36.501: E/log_tag(9345): Error parsing dataorg.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
and when i put my cursor near the Table row ot setText i am getting java doc not found     org.json.JSONArray.JSONArray(String json) throws JSONException


Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle applicationId is the final PackageName for playstore.
So, check that "com.example.my_app" in the Gradle.